# Python While Loop not executing else block

Tags: python

```
def jump_slide():

    num=int(input('Enter a number :'))
    if num>20:
        print('slide under')
    else:
        print('jump over')
```

The above runs just fine when not in a while loop.
But once in the loop below, it completely ignores the else block

```
while True:
   jump_slide()
```

Any suggestion please.
I'm new to Python

Comment: There's something you're not showing us. Your code works fine for me, whether inside a `while` loop or not.

Comment: kill your kernel and try again. The code here does not have any problems. The code you're running in memory might not be the code that's written here.

Comment: That is not the behavior I experience when running your code. Please post the rest of the code in context.

Comment: It would help if you post your whole code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is dependent on the input that you give to the variable num in the function `jump_slide()'.

If you give a value less than 20 to the num variable, it will execute the else block.

otherwise your code is fine as far as syntax is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

`if-else`is a conditional statement so depending on the condition inside the `if` it will execute either of the statements.

An example in your program:

```
Say you enter a number 30 when you run the program, it will print "slide under" but suppose 
if you enter 10 your program will print "jump over".
```

So depending on your input it will print either of the statements but not both.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. One more way for doing your work is.

```
def jump_slide():

while(True):
    num=int(input('Enter a number :'))
    if num>20:
        print('slide under')
    else:
        print('jump over')
    if num==-1:
        break
```

dont  put while loop here.

```
jump_slide()
```

now if you enter num greater than 20  if execute and "Slide under" print on the screen
if you enter number smaller than 20 else execute and "Jump over" print on the screen
if you press -1 than your loop will break and code after the function will execute or the program ends